# How to conditionally filter a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'city': ['New York','New York','New York','Los Angeles','Los Angeles','Houston','Houston','Houston'],
'airport': ['LGA', 'EWR', 'JFK', 'LAX', 'BUR', 'IAH', 'HOU', 'EFD'],
'distance': [38, 50, 32, 8, 50, 90, 78, 120]
}
df

    city           airport    distance
0   New York       LGA        38
1   New York       EWR        50
2   New York       JFK        32
3   Los Angeles    LAX        8
4   Los Angeles    BUR        50
5   Houston        IAH        90
6   Houston        HOU        78
7   Houston        EFD        120
```

I would like to output a separate dataframe based on the following logic:

1. if the value in the `distance` column is 40 **or less** between a given city and associated airport, than keep the row
2. if, within a given city, there is no distance below 40, then show only the shortest (lowest) distance

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
    city           airport    distance
0   New York       LGA        38
1   New York       JFK        32
3   Los Angeles    LAX        8
4   Houston        HOU        78      <-- this is returned, even though it's more than 40
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: with shortest (lowest) you mean of all rows of the same city, keep the row with the lowest distance I guess?

Comment: Yes, the shortest (lowest) of all the rows **of the same city**.

Comment: as far as I understand he wants to look at the groups of the cities, if there is no value under 40, then only keep the smallest over 40, if there are smaller values than 40, keep all of the smaller ones

Comment: @all -- I made point #2 more precise:  if there is no distance less than 40 for a given city/airport pairing, then show only pairing with the shortest distance (see the case for Houston in the example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in your case do with `drop_duplicates` then `combine_first`

```
out = df.sort_values('distance').drop_duplicates('city').combine_first(df.loc[df['distance']<40])
Out[228]: 
         city airport  distance
0     NewYork     LGA        38
2     NewYork     JFK        32
3  LosAngeles     LAX         8
6     Houston     HOU        78
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, which is based on the following ideas:

1. Create a dataframe that only contains rows where `distance` is lower or equal to 40.
2. Create another dataframe whose rows correspond to the minimum of `distance` per group of `cities`.
3. Concatenate the above two dataframes.
4. Remove the duplicates.

```
(pd.concat([tdf.loc[tdf.distance.le(40)], 
            tdf.iloc[tdf.groupby('city')['distance'].idxmin()]])
 .drop_duplicates()
)
```

Output:

```
          city airport  distance
0     New York     LGA        38
2     New York     JFK        32
3  Los Angeles     LAX         8
6      Houston     HOU        78
```